# Calling of functions not working properly

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am working on a computer science project, I need to make a Wheel of Fortune game - basically, get a random word, show blank spaces, and have the player(s) guess the letters to form the word. Right now, I've got the parts where the word is chosen, hidden (switching the letters for blank spaces), and shown. Now, I am on the part of enable player turns to start guessing the letters. I have set up a button to call a function which calls other functions (each turn is broken down into multiple parts, such as asking for a guess, checking what type of guess it is, and checking if that guess is in the word). For some reason, this bigger function is, when calling them, only calling the first function, and spamming that single function. Why is it not going down the list of functions and calling each in order?

Here is the code that relates to that part:

```js
function player1() {
  console.log("Player 1 is going.");
  nowGoing = 1;
  player1Elements.style.display = "block";
  alert(player1Name + " it is your turn. What do you guess?");
  prompt();
  checkGuessType();
  checkGuess();
}

function prompt() {
  console.log("Prompting");
  var playerGuess;
  playerGuess = prompt("What letter would you like to guess?");
  checkGuessType(playerGuess);
}

function checkGuessType(playerGuess) {
  console.log("Checking");
  if (playerGuess.length > 1) {
    console.log(player1Name + " guessed a word.");
  } else if (playerGuess == "a" || playerGuess == "e" || playerGuess == "i" || playerGuess == "o" || playerGuess == "u") {
    console.log(player1Name + " guessed a vowel.");
  } else {
    console.log(player1Name + " guessed a consonant.");
  }
}
```

All that appears in the console (the console.logs are exactly for this purpose) are 6000 lines saying "Prompting", not "Prompting" and "Checking". If there is any more code I should show, please let me know!

If anyone could help me out, that would be great!

Edit: I tried changing the code to the following (basically changing to a global variable), but it still didn't work. I'm not sure why, as the same thing happens.

```
function player1() {

  console.log("Player 1 is going.");
    nowGoing = 1;
    player1Elements.style.display = "block";
    
    alert(playerName1 + " it is your turn. What do you guess?");
  prompt();
  checkGuessType();
  checkGuess();

}

function prompt() {

    // console.log("Prompting");
    
    playerGuess = prompt("What letter would you like to guess?");

}

function checkGuessType() {

    console.log("Checking");

  if (playerGuess.length > 1) {

    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a word.");

  } else if (playerGuess == "a" || playerGuess == "e" || playerGuess == "i" || playerGuess == "o" || playerGuess == "u") {

    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a vowel.");

  } else {

    console.log(playerName1 + " guessed a consonant.");

  }

}
```

Comment: `prompt()` calls `checkGuessType()` and then `player1()` calls it again. But the second call doesn't pass the argument that's needed, so you should get an error when it tries to use `playerGuess.length`.

Comment: You haven't shown `checkGuess()`, but since you don't pass it an argument how is it supposed to know what the guess is?

Comment: Thank you for responding! The code is supposed to get the guess from a variable whose value is given from a prompt, but that prompt never occurs - only the flooding of the console with the "Prompting" statements. Also, I have not set up the checkGuess() function, I'll do that next after I can figure out this error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that "Prompting" is appearing over and over is that you provide `playerGuess` as the argument for `checkGuessType` in `prompt` but `playerGuess` is just another call to `prompt` so it starts recursing. However, `prompt` never returns any value under any condition, so the recursion will never resolve to a value causing the stack of function calls to collapse and execute the call to `checkGuessType`, so you never see a repetition of the `console.log` in `checkGuessType`.

EDIT

After your edit I just wanted to point at what I think the problem is directly:

```js
function prompt() {

    // console.log("Prompting");
    
    playerGuess = prompt("What letter would you like to guess?");

}
```

Within the scope of your function,  `prompt` just refers to the function itself. This is causing a recursion. That recursive stack will never end because nothing returns from `prompt`, thus eventually causing a stack overflow error. If you don't mean to be starting a recursive stack, you need to rename your `prompt` function to something other than what the built in prompt function is called.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

I tried changing some of the code (switching the variable type), but the same error occurs. I edited the original post with the new information, could you please check that?

Comment: Using a variable doesn't call the function again.

Comment: @Barmar it wasn't using the variable that I was saying would call it again, but the variable was just another function call to `prompt` itself, which would call `prompt` again itself, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion -- he named his function `prompt()` which is the same as the built-in function that asks for input.

Comment: @Bubbly I have added more information, does that make sense / seem to be the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it seemed the problem was due to the wording of my functions. The issue seems to be fixed now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bubbly If you believe this is the correct answer, would you mind marking it as such?